# Lock tag [new] or make synonym for [new-operator]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/new) was created [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29226618/3001761) today on Stack Overflow, and the subject matter is clearly identical to [new-operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/new-operator). I do not have 5 reputation in [new-operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/new-operator), so I cannot suggest a synonym - and it's not clear to me whether this should be made a synonym or simply locked.

Comment: There are no questions tagged [tag:new], and quite a few `[new*]` tags: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/newline+or+new-operator+or+newrelic+or+newsletter+or+news-feed+or+news+or+newsstand-kit+or+newtons-method+or+new-window+or+newrelic-platform+or+news-ticker+or+newlib+or+new-project+or+newtype+or+newid+or+new-style-class+or+newrow+or+newsql+or+newlisp+or+newsequentialid

Comment: There was one question - I edited the tag after rejecting the [new] tag wiki which showed up in my reviews. Are you suggesting the tag should be locked?

Comment: Yes, I think it probably should - there are other, more specific tags that would always be better.

Comment: Blacklisting is the term you are looking for.  That is only done in very rare cases.  When you see bad or duplicate tags like this show up, just edit them out.